# React add components dynamically from dynamically added component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

What I am trying to do is to add components iteratively from the last dynamically added component.

|dynamically added component| ----on click----> |added new component| ---on click--> | added another component|

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Product from '../../Product';
import Project from '../../Project';


const NewProject = () => {
    const [productList, setProductList] = useState([]);
    const addProduct = () => {
        setProductList([...productList, <Product addProduct={addProduct} key={productList.length}></Product>]);
    };

    return <React.Fragment>
        <Project addProduct={addProduct}>
        </Project>
        {productList}

    </React.Fragment>

}

export default NewProject;
```

Basically, I'm passing `addProduct` const to the `Product` component and it executes the `addProduct` function again. I see addProduct is triggered but I don't see component came. I think I'm mixing some states there.

Adding Product component from Project component props works fine by the way. But I want to do the same with added product components.

Comment: Are there any unique properties for a Product that could go in your productList array? Otherwise, all you need is a counter, not an array.

Comment: No unique properties for a Product. I just need to duplicate the Product Component by clicking the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exact problem but the way I use it is a little bit different instead of saving Product Component to the list, I only save the product data then I create a another function to render them into components and then pass it in return like below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Product from '../../Product';
import Project from '../../Project';


const NewProject = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([{}]);
    
    const addProduct = () => {
        setProducts([...products, {}]);
    };

    const renderProducts = () => products.map((_, i) => <Product addProduct={addProduct}/>)

    return <>{renderProducts()}</>;
};

export default NewProject;
```

Comment: btw <></> is equal to <React.Fragment></React.Fragment>

Comment: Replace `{renderProducts()}` with the contents of that function. The declaration of it as a function is superfluous.

Comment: This seems working thank you very much, but I have a few questions.

What is the difference between [] and [{}] you still declare a list of objects?

Also, initially I see a Product component, how can I get rid of it? I want initial one by clicking as well.

Comment: By editing [{}] to [] I got rid of the initial Product component. Thank you :)

Comment: I have a style of writing short code and that may seem a little odd to some people it is just a shortcut to get rid of the first component.

Comment: @DevAddict - shortcuts are usually shorter